# LabVIEW to C# Conversion

Tags: c#, labview

What are all the Softwares needed for LabVIEW to C# Conversion(Converting VIs into C# Code)Except LabVIEW and Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: Please refine your question: do you want to call LabVIEW code from C#? or literally convert the source code from LabVIEW to C# (in this case are you looking for something automatic)

Comment: @CharlesB : Yes . I need to conver the VI's in LabVIEW into C# code.

Comment: Doesn't LabVIEW expose VIs via a .NET interface?

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for automatic conversion of LabVIEW code to C#, no such tool exist, you have to rewrite it by hand.

Comment: I'm not looking for any automatic conversion tool , friend. I'm using `Measurement Studio` for this. I just need to know any other software for this.

Comment: I'm still not well woke up, so please be more clear :) You're using Measurement Studio for what? Are you looking for an alternative to Measurement Studio for data acquisition?

Comment: `Measurement Studio` provides LabView support for .Net. So i'm using that for my conversion project. i need to know , whether there is any other software that provides such support i.e that provde dll for `NI's VI`

Comment: OK got it; not sure if it exist, but now your question is more precise, maybe you can edit the question again to add these details.

Answer (score 4):

LabVIEW VI's are binary and as far as I know there is no other tool, besides LabVIEW itself, that understands them.

I think that by using Measurement Studio you could interface with NI hardware in .NET, but I don't think you can access all the VI's built in to LabVIEW from dlls.

Answer (score 2):

Not C# but may be useful in certain instances:

[NI LabVIEW C Generator](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/209015)

Answer (score 1):

No tool exists (that National Instruments knows of) that does what you're looking for.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

We have [pylabview](https://github.com/mefistotelis/pylabview) which converts VIs to XML (and back).
Whether it will convert everything to XML or leave some binary chunks depends on LV version used to create te files though. If Block Diagram was converted to XML, then you could write a parser which reads that and transforms to any output.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, if you want to call LabVIEW code from C#, it is better to convert your VIs into dll library, then import it from C# like any assembly.

Check this [example](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/A3804F88FCDB1E6286257CE00043C1A7).You may also watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70THpoCHFgo) for basic creation of LabVIEW dll library

Answer (score 0):

Manually rewrite the code is the only way. Might not be as painful as you think. I just converted a few LabVIEW projects to Python scripts and the Python script was surprisingly easier and much smaller in comparison.

Good luck!